# Objective-c release called so many times

Tags: objective-c, release

the release method of my root view controller is called 38 times but I not calling release, why it occur?

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_viewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

---

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(oneway void)release
{
    NSLog(@"release called");
    [super release];
}

@end
```

---

outpout

```
2013-04-09 19:47:36.060 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.063 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.064 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.065 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.065 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.066 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.067 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.068 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.072 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.073 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.074 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.075 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.077 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.080 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.081 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.081 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.082 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.108 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.110 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.111 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.112 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.134 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.144 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.158 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.161 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.170 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.180 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.182 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.193 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.197 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.198 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.199 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.202 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.208 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.208 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.218 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.220 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
2013-04-09 19:47:36.220 TesteRelease[44985:c07] release called
```

---

I'm not using ARC.

Comment: Your view controller object can be passed around by several framework objects. Also, even if _you_ don't use ARC, maybe Apple does; and ARC is not light on calling retain/release. I don't think it's relevant to log release calls, anyways. It's going to matter only when `dealloc` is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parts of the framework are retaining and releasing (or autoreleasing) the object as they feel appropriate. This is one of the many reasons why you are encouraged not to try to track retain counts precisely — you don't need to know all these retains and releases are happening, as they have nothing to do with you.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your view controller is being added to autorelease pools as it is handed around through system libraries.  But as long as you're confident that your code is managing the view controller correctly, you should just ignore this as background noise.